# How to add parameters to the included task files in Concourse CI

Tags: concourse

If task file (`file: task.yml`) in pipeline (`pipeline.yml`) config needs to contain some `{{properties}}`, what is a proper way to add them?

In my case, I want to use a custom docker image from repository that uses authentication, and I don't want to hardcode/commit credentials in task yml itself.

Is the a way to do that currently without moving task config to the main pipeline yml?

Clarification: I want to parameterize `task.yml` file itself (for example, `input: {{input_name}}`).

Comment: This is soon to come. It has been merged into `Master` on the Concourse GitHub repo. See > https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/454 ...

Answer (score 3):

In your `task.yml` you can specify required params, e.g:

```
params:
  USERNAME:
  PASSWORD:
```

And then provide them in `pipeline.yml`:

```
jobs:
- name: my-job 
  plan:
  - get: ci-files
  - task: my-task
    file: ci-files/task.yml
    params:
      USERNAME: {{username}}
      PASSWORD: {{password}}
```

Configure pipeline as:

`fly set-pipeline -p pipeline-name -c pipeline.yml -v=USERNAME=my-username -v=PASSWORD=my-password`

Then these params will be available to you as environment variables inside your task.

Comment: I've meant something entirely different: I want to parameterize `task.yml` file itself (for example, `input: {{input_name}}`)

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. Only passing params from pipeline as mentioned https://concourse.ci/task-step.html#task-params